# Looking for a ritual I saw somewhere that can resurrect a kindred after final death

Tags: world-of-darkness, rituals, content-identification, vampire-the-dark-ages

I am looking for a ritual I saw somewhere that can resurrect a kindred after final death. This is what I remember:

- I am sure it was in one of the Dark Ages books.
- It wasn't traditional blood magic.
- The only specific thing I remember about the ritual is that it involved a specialty prepared room with runes painted all over the walls.

Hope that helps

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and check out the [help] to learn more about the site. I think this question could be really interesting, but I find it a bit hard to read. Could you [edit] to include more details and possibly to add some punctuation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lazarus Rises - Biblical Necromancy 6**

*V20 Dark Ages Tome of Secrets* p104:

> The  necromancer  tattoos a Cainite target with tiny symbols denoting
> her faith, while lining a room with the same script. When the target
> would suffer Final Death, he instead disappears in a cloud of ashes
> and reappears — albeit in torpor — in the prepared room.

I suspect this is what you are asking about. It only resurrects if prepared before Final Death though. No performing the ritual after the fact.